# SQL and DevExpress ASPx Grid data (display data 'M' as 'Male')

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, devexpress

I have an ASPx Gridview control which displays a bunch of data.  In the database, a person gender is listed as M or F.  And when I display that information in the grid, it comes up as the same M or F.  But I need it to display Male or Female.  How can I make it so that the the result is converted to that string before displaying?

```
                                                            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Gender" VisibleIndex="14" Caption="Patient's Gender" Width="100px" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                                        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" <%# Eval("Gender").ToString() == "M" ? "Male" : "Female"  %> ></asp:Label>
```

Comment: What about inside                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Gender" VisibleIndex="14" Caption="Patient's Gender" Width="100px" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
               </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

Comment: You have to make the column as template field and then put label like what I have put in the answer.